# Explanation needed for HTTP codes

Tags: http, nginx, error-code

We had setup uWSGI + Nginx + Django application.  When we hit the URL from browser most of the time it works but at times it fail with '502 Bad Gateway error'

I understand 502 stands for 'bad gateway error'.  However, I am not sure what 560 (which is next to 502) denotes

```
Access.log

10.xxx.xxx.xx - - [08/Jun/2019:08:00:32 -0400] "GET /Home/ HTTP/1.1" 502 560 "https://example.com/graph/Home/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64 ; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
```

Where can I get the list / explanation for HTTP error codes ?  Kindly explain

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate ?

Comment: `560` is the length of the response in bytes. The default access log format is [shown here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format).

Comment: @CodeWalker  I am not trying to authenticate.  Just loading some data on hit of the URL

Comment: @RichardSmith  Thank you.  Where can I get the complete list ?  Any URL for hat

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @RichardSmith I think you should publish your explanation about `$body_bytes_sent` as an answer, since this is the right answer and it deserves some upvotes.